# Timezone not supported Talend Open Studio

Tags: mysql, oracle, talend

I have created one talend job which load data from oracle db to mysql db.
But while running the job i am getting following error

```
[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3440
[statistics] connected
Exception in component tOracleInput_1
java.sql.SQLException: Timezone not supported
at oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPLTZ.TimeZoneAdjust(TIMESTAMPLTZ.java:1707)
at oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPLTZ.toTimestamp(TIMESTAMPLTZ.java:1117)
at   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getTimestampValue(OracleStatement.java:509    2)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getTimestamp(OracleResultSetImpl.java:    689)
```

I am not able to figure what this error mean.
for reference there is time stamp field in source db which as following format

1980-08-05 19:00:59.0 - Source Format
1980-08-05 19:00:59 - Target Format

Comment: do you have a transformation(Map) step between the export and the import? you can define there the format of the timestamp(s)

Comment: @thomas yes i have setup transformation map setup in between them but i dont know how i can map these two timestamps can you give an example of expression or point me to a any blog post ? thanks for replying.